# Windows: Add samba printer at each logon

Tags: windows, printer, batch, network-printer

All,

I currently have a samba printer shared at `\\%ServerIP%\Printer1` which requires credentials to connect.

Users can easily add the printer with the printer wizard.  However, the printer will stop working after a day or two on Windows machines.

To combat this problem, I would like to add the printer each time a user logs on with a script.  I have tried this:

```
echo Adding Printer1 at %ServerIP%

rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n\\%ServerIP%\Printer1

echo Restarting print spooler so that printer is accessible in dialogs

start /wait sc stop spooler
start /wait sc start spooler

echo Done. Exiting...
```

But this doesn't work if the printer isn't already installed.  How can I make a more robust solution?

Thanks!